# VSCode and Vue: Unexpected character '‌'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode for a somewhat large scale Vuejs project, however, I keep getting weird unexpected character errors when I write any arrow functions or anything that involves brackets. For instance if I were to add an empty `computed` in the middle of `methods` and `created` like this:

```
methods: {
    method1() {
        // sample code here
    },
    method2(){
        // sample code here
    }
},
computed:‌{
    
},

created() {
    if(this.condition){
        require("prismjs/components/prism-python")
    }
},
```

I'd get this error:

```
Syntax Error: SyntaxError: /home/me/Documents/project/src/views/folder/file.vue: Unexpected character '‌' (86:13)

  84 |         }
  85 |     },
> 86 |     computed:‌{
     |              ^
  87 |         
  88 |     },
  89 | 


 @ ./src/views/folder/file.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-292 1:308-311 1:313-602 1:313-602
 @ ./src/views/folder/file.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.175:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

But if I were to copy-paste a `computed` from another working file in place of the current `computed`, removed whatever was inside and code as normal, everything works just fine, so it's safe to assume VSCode is inserting *something* (that I can't see, apparently).

I don't have any extensions except Vetur, and I even tried disabling/reinstalling to see if that was the problem.
I've tried everything, from fiddling with the auto-insert settings, to anything short of straight-up reinstalling VSCode. I've looked all over google, but for some reason I‌ can't find anyone else whos had this specific problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What wiil happen if you insert a space like this: `computed:‌ {`?

Comment: @Anatoly Same exact error.

Comment: Make sure [View][Render Control Characters] is checked top menu. It's possible non-printing UTF characters are being entered. What is your locale? Alternatively, change the file encoding to ASCII and see what happens.

Comment: You have a hidden character in there.

Comment: what if you edit the file in another editor, replace just the semicolon and then execute the script, what happens then?

Comment: @RandyCasburn That did it thanks! Can you please answer this question so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment: Make sure [View][Render Control Characters] is checked top menu. It's possible non-printing UTF characters are being entered. What is your locale? Alternatively, change the file encoding to ASCII and see what happens.